# Is it possible to obtain a column's Bucket_Count value with TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've been working on creating a Memory Optimized SQL Database with SQL Server 2016; I was wondering if it is possibly to acquire the current BUCKET_COUNT value for a specific Column in a table?

My goal is to be able to create an SQL Server Agent Job to automatically alter the value based on the current number of records in the table I'm working with

Thanks.

Comment: Bucket count is a property of the index. So is in `sys.hash_indexes`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.

Comment: You can also check the view `sys.dm_db_xtp_hash_index_stats`